# Syntax Error: line 0, col 95: Error: Expected Literal, got ''

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I get this a `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 95: Error: Expected Literal, got 'value'` error when I try to  execute the following query:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb
       ->join('a.categories', 'cat')
       ->where($qb->expr()->in('cat.name', $category));
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

The mapped field is as followed:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Camten\TestBundle\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"}, inversedBy="articles")
 */
 private $categories;
```

Thought it was a problem with the data type but I really can't find what's wrong.

Comment: what is `$category`?

Comment: `$category` is the variable I've set as a parameter for the method

Comment: `public function getAvecCategory($category){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

        $qb->join('a.categories', 'cat')->where($qb->expr()->in('cat.name', $category));

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }`

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was: What contains `$category`: id, Object, the category name?

Comment: The category name. I thought that's where the problem was coming from but even when it's a id I get an error page

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `setParameter()` to bind parameter to dql variables
See below,

```
qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

$qb
   ->join('a.categories', 'cat')
   ->where('cat.name = :nameParam') 
   ->setParameter('nameParam', $category);
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

*(I named it `nameParam` to show it has nothing to do with `cat.name`)*

If you want to use the `$qb->expr()->`* methods you should use `eq()` and not `in()`

```
qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

$qb
   ->join('a.categories', 'cat')
   ->where($qb->expr()->eq('cat.name',':nameParam'))
   ->setParameter('nameParam', $category);
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```